# Rails app runs only in development mode, no log in production

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails

I've created super simple rails app

```
rails test
cd test/
script/generate controller home index
rm public/index.html

# uncommented map.root :controller => "home" in config/routes.rb
```

When I run app in development mode, it works just fine and everything get logged

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/rails/test/public

    ErrorLog /opt/rails/test/log/error.log
    CustomLog /opt/rails/testlog/access.log combined

    RailsEnv development
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I change to RailsEnv production,

```
RailsEnv production
```

I get this ugly error page

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

and there is absolutely nothing in either error.log or production.log, however, in access.log, I can see the request being logged.

I'm running Ubuntu x64 Jaunty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the ssl_requirement plugin from github. You'll get an email with the error message/session dump etc... when running in production.

http://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/tree/master

Also, the command "rm public/index.php" should be "rm public/index.html".

I would check the logs in /var/log/apache2 just to be sure that you haven't missed something. I know the logs are supposed to be in your custom dir, but...

Comment: heh, it really did log to /var/log/apache2 ...

Comment: Cool, glad you found the prob.  By the way, I made a mistake, it's not the ssl_requirement plugin...it's the exception_notifier plugin.